# How to merge two particular rows into single row and reaming rows are same using stored procedure SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, join, stored-procedures

I have data like this. first row of **Id 1** from particular time period and second row of **id 1** is another time period. so now want to combined id and name which are same in the two time periods reaming are same.if there is no orders from that time period its should be display 0 or null.

```
    Id  Name    Qty Price
    ----------------------
    1   Rose    4   540
    1   Rose    1   640
    2   Lilly   5   550
    2   Lilly   18  360
    3   Grand   2   460
    3   Grand   10  360
    4   lotus   0    0
    4   Lotus   9   580
```

now I want data like this..

```
Id  Name    Qty   Price
             4     540
1   rose
             1      640

             5      550
2    Lilly
             18     360

             2      460
3   Grand
             10     360

             0       0
4   Lotus      
             9     580
```

This is my procedure

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Orders] 
(
    @Startdate varchar(30),                  
    @Enddate varchar(30),
    @Startdate1 varchar(30),
    @Enddate1 varchar(30)
) 
--[Sp_Orders] '03/01/2016','03/15/2016','02/01/2016','02/28/2016'
AS 
BEGIN 
    ---First Duration----
    SELECT DISTINCT
        op.ProductId as id, op.Price as Prc, 
        sc.SubCategoryName as ScName,
        COUNT(op.ProductId) AS Qty, 
        ROUND(SUM(op.Price * op.Quantity), 0) AS Revenue,
    FROM
        orderdetails od 
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             Orderid, Productid, ProductFeatures, Price, Quantity 
         FROM
             OrderProducts) op ON od.Orderid = op.Orderid
    INNER JOIN
        products p ON p.productid = op.productid
    INNER JOIN
        subcategory sc ON sc.subcategoryid = p.subcategoryid
    WHERE
        CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(50), od.DeliveryDate, 101)) BETWEEN @Startdate AND @Enddate
    GROUP BY 
        op.ProductID, op.Price, sc.SubCategoryName

    ---Second Duration----
    SELECT DISTINCT
        op.ProductID AS id, op.Price AS Prc,
        sc.SubCategoryName AS ScName,
        COUNT(op.ProductId) AS Qty, 
        ROUND(SUM(op.Price * op.Quantity), 0) AS Revenue,
    FROM
        orderdetails od 
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             Orderid, Productid, ProductFeatures, Price, Quantity 
         FROM
             OrderProducts) op ON od.Orderid = op.Orderid
    INNER JOIN
        products p ON p.productid = op.productid
    INNER JOIN
        subcategory sc ON sc.subcategoryid = p.subcategoryid
    WHERE
        CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(50),od.DeliveryDate,101)) BETWEEN @Startdate1 AND @Enddate1
    GROUP BY
        op.ProductID, op.Price, sc.SubCategoryName
END
```

Comment: Do the original id always come in pairs?  What output do you want for a single or triple occurrence?

Comment: Are you trying to format the data in SQL directly so that there are two rows per `Name` without the `Name` showing up in the second row? If that's the case you should really consider another solution. If you must do it in SQL, i.e. you are required to print these results to screen, then you're going to have to create your own magic with appending text, which is going to be a mess and not worth it.

Comment: What you mention two time periods remaining but there are no time periods in your data examples.  So there is no idea of when/how to apply the 0 to your results.  Also, sql-server and other database engines are not like excel the only way you would get the result table you show is to actually repeat the ID and name per row which is just going to give you your original table

Comment: I agree with Matt. Leave the formatting up to Excel or some other reporting tool.

Comment: There is no periods in your example and in the result the rows are somehow offset, so what do you exactly want?

Comment: if i will get (Lotus )15 orders in that time zone that should be display in that time zone.. if there is no orders it should be zero

Comment: time period is there...  1   Rose    4   540(from 01-01-2015 to 01-05-2015)
    1   Rose    1   640(from 01-07-2015 to 01-10-2015)

Comment: Time periods are not present even if I go to edit yoru question.  Why do you want this format from SQL if you want a report for grouping purposes in Excel or something SSRS would be a better place for this. Not that it can't be done is SQL just shouldn't because you are separating the values from a discernable key/name which means that you can't do any further calculations or ever bring the data back without mainlining row order.

Comment: @Matt time periods are there...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also: if you have **dates** like `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` - do ***NOT*** use `varchar(n)` datatypes for these! Use the **proper** datatype, either `DATE` (if you're not interested in time), or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need time, too

Comment: @marc_s Okey..  i will use datetime

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your Question and Comments:

Schema for your case

```
    SELECT * INTO #TAB FROM(      
    SELECT 1 ID, 'ROSE' NAME, 4 QTY, 540 PRICE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 , 'ROSE' , 1 , 640
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 , 'LILLY' , 5 , 550
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 , 'LILLY' , 18 ,360
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 , 'GRAND' , 2 , 460
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 , 'GRAND' , 10 ,360
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 , NULL,NULL,NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 , 'LOTUS' , 9 , 580
    ) AS A
```

And the Logic to display is as below

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN SNO=1 THEN CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(250)) ELSE '' END ID,
    CASE WHEN SNO=1 THEN ISNULL(NAME,'') ELSE '' END NAME,ISNULL(Qty,0)Qty
   ,ISNuLL(Price,0)Price FROM (

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition  by Name, Id   ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) SNO
   ,ID, NAME , Qty, Price, ID AS ID2 FROM #TAB


    )AS A
    ORDER BY ID2, NAME DESC
```

Try this from your Procedure. And may need to do type cast based on your actual datatypes

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[SP_ORDERS] 
    (
    @STARTDATE VARCHAR(30),                  
    @ENDDATE VARCHAR(30),
    @STARTDATE1 VARCHAR(30),
    @ENDDATE1 VARCHAR(30)
    ) 
    --[SP_ORDERS] '03/01/2016','03/15/2016','02/01/2016','02/28/2016'
    AS 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT CASE WHEN SNO=1 THEN CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(250)) ELSE '' END ID,CASE WHEN SNO=1 THEN ISNULL(SCNAME,'') ELSE '' END NAME,ISNULL(QTY,0)QTY,ISNULL(REVENUE,0)PRICE FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY SCNAME, ID   ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) SNO, ID, SCNAME , QTY, REVENUE, ID AS ID2 FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT OP.PRODUCTID AS ID,OP.PRICE AS PRC,SC.SUBCATEGORYNAME AS SCNAME,COUNT(OP.PRODUCTID) AS QTY, ROUND(SUM(OP.PRICE * OP.QUANTITY), 0) AS REVENUE
        FROM ORDERDETAILS OD INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT ORDERID,PRODUCTID,PRODUCTFEATURES,PRICE,QUANTITY FROM ORDERPRODUCTS ) OP ON OD.ORDERID=OP.ORDERID
        INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.PRODUCTID=OP.PRODUCTID
        INNER JOIN SUBCATEGORY SC ON SC.SUBCATEGORYID=P.SUBCATEGORYID
        WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),OD.DELIVERYDATE,101)) BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
        GROUP BY OP.PRODUCTID,OP.PRICE,SC.SUBCATEGORYNAME
        ---SECOND DURATION----
        UNION ALL --ADDED NOW
        SELECT DISTINCT OP.PRODUCTID AS ID,OP.PRICE AS PRC,SC.SUBCATEGORYNAME AS SCNAME,COUNT(OP.PRODUCTID) AS QTY, ROUND(SUM(OP.PRICE * OP.QUANTITY), 0) AS REVENUE
        FROM ORDERDETAILS OD INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT ORDERID,PRODUCTID,PRODUCTFEATURES,PRICE,QUANTITY FROM ORDERPRODUCTS ) OP ON OD.ORDERID=OP.ORDERID
        INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.PRODUCTID=OP.PRODUCTID
        INNER JOIN SUBCATEGORY SC ON SC.SUBCATEGORYID=P.SUBCATEGORYID
        WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),OD.DELIVERYDATE,101)) BETWEEN @STARTDATE1 AND @ENDDATE1

        GROUP BY OP.PRODUCTID,OP.PRICE,SC.SUBCATEGORYNAME
        )
        AS A
        )B
        ORDER BY ID2, NAME 

    END
```

Comment: Ok sure. I will try to help you @Maybe

Comment: but see the output carefully what you have given is not giving exact result

Comment: are you talking about the last line with 0 Qty and Price? @mohan111

Comment: i shared my procedure...plz look at

Comment: @ShakeerMirza NO Rose is one column and price ,Qty another column so over all 3 columns ..in Tree View Under Rose --> Qty and Price

Comment: I didnt get you @mohan111

Comment: your logic will give side by side result ... SO asked Rose below QTY and Price ..not beside of Rose

Comment: @ShakeerMirza.. please explain i cant' understand.. i want to merge data with first period of time i.e (@startDate to @EndDate) and second period of time  (@startDate1 to @EndDate1)..

Comment: @ShakeerMirza if get roses  5 orders from (@startDate to @EndDate)  this time period and also get roses  6 orders from (@startDate1 to @EndDate1) both are id and name must be shown in single row and Qty, price as well as..please understand

Comment: Sorry for late. U need to merge those results with Union ALL operator. By taking the Merged result into a sub query add one more column with ROW_NUM. It will generate numbers by grouping Name & ID. After that u need to take into again a sub query. In the outer query u will display only Name and ID if Row_Num =1. Rest of the columns as it is. @Maybe

Comment: Did you observe my Test code given at first?? Is it your requirement or not?? If it suits your requirement only choose my second code (Procedure). I am not getting what u r saying by "both are id and name must be shown in single row and Qty, price as well as" @Maybe

Comment: @ShakeerMirza how will i know that id came from which time period i.e (@startDate to @EndDate) or (@startDate1 to @EndDate1)... I want data based on mentioned time periods..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data i have given this Out put but if the data is inconsistent it may not give accurate results if you see the Expected Output it gives exact same

```
    Declare @Table1 TABLE 
        (Id VARCHAR(10), Name varchar(5),Qty VARCHAR(10), Price varchar(10))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        (Id, Name,Qty, Price)
    VALUES
        (1, 'Rose',4, 540),
        (1, 'Rose',1, 640),
        (2, 'Lilly',5, 550),
        (2, 'Lilly',18, 360),
        (3, 'Grand',2, 460),
        (3, 'Grand',10, 360),
        (4,'Lotus',0,0),
        (4, 'Lotus',9, 580)
    ;
```

**SCRIPT**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    Select 
    CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN ID ELSE NULL END ID,
    CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Name ELSE NULL END NAME,
    Qty, 
    Price 
        from (
    select 
    Id, 
    Name,
    Qty, 
    Price,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID,NAME ORDER BY NAME)RN 
        FROM 
            @Table1)T)

    Select CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN T.Id ELSE '' END ID,
    CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN T.Name ELSE '' END Name,
    CASE WHEN RN IN (1,3)   THEN ISNULL(T.Qty,0) ELSE '' END qty,
    CASE WHEN RN IN (1,3)   THEN ISNULL(T.Price,0) ELSE '' END qty from (
    Select 
        T.ID,
        T.NAME,
        c.Qty,
        C.Price,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.ID,T.NAME ORDER BY T.NAME)RN 
        from @Table1 T
    INNER JOIN CTE C
    ON T.Id = C.ID 
    AND T.Name = C.NAME 
    OR (T.Qty = C.Qty OR T.Price = C.Price ))T
    WHERE T.RN <> 4
```

Comment: @maybe can you please look into this one and tell me your concerns

Comment: in my stored procedure i'm using 4 different tables .. i cant get your query.. @mohan111